# Get the local user during ssh session

Tags: shell, unix, aix

Is it possible to display the local user on remote host?
eg.:

`local_user@ownpc$ ssh remote_user@server`

then

```
echo $some_variable_containing_local_user
```

that results local_user

Purpose: I have a very **limited** read access to a UNIX server, i'd like to perform scp from remote to local over the current ssh session. Performed via a shell script, regardless of who logged in. (without any additional installs or local variable modifications)

Ps.: I am **not** looking for `scp ssh:user@host/folder/file /home/user/folder`

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think any such variables exist by default. You can set arbitrary variables through ssh but the remote daemon needs to support them.

Comment: I don't have any ssh access right now. Doesn't `ssh remote_user@server 'echo $USER'` give you the remote username? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unquoted here-doc allows local variables to be expanded before passing the commands to ssh

```
local_user@ownpc$ ssh remote_user@server <<END
echo you are $USER
END
```

should output

```
you are local_user
```

That may give you a basis to script your remote actions in the here-doc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your situation but both of these methods work for me:

```
ssh remote_user@remote_host whoami
```

and

```
ssh remote_user@remote_host 'echo $USER'
```

The first executes "whoami" on the remote host while the second echos out what $USER is set to in the remote shell.  I'm a little surprised the second one works because often ssh remote executing does not start a shell but it appears to work anyway.